# React Native - fontFamily "Inter-Black" is not a system font and has not been loaded through Font.loadAsync

Tags: ios, react-native, fonts, expo

I've already seen every stack question about this issue but nothing works. Already changed versions, fonts, type of fonts and the "old" Font.loadAsync. My code is basically equal of the offcial documentation: [Font Expo Documentation](https://docs.expo.dev/versions/latest/sdk/font/)

The error:
[image]

My device is IOS. Here's my code:

```
import { useCallback} from 'react';
import { View, Text } from 'react-native';
import { NavigationContainer } from '@react-navigation/native';
import { createNativeStackNavigator } from '@react-navigation/native-stack';
import Menu from './screens/menu';
import FEMIntro from './screens/femIntro';
import { useFonts } from 'expo-font';
import * as SplashScreen from 'expo-splash-screen';

// Keep the splash screen visible while we fetch resources
SplashScreen.preventAutoHideAsync();

export default function App() {
  let [fontsLoaded] = useFonts({
'Inter-Black': require('./assets/fonts/Inter-Black.otf'),
//'WorkSansRegular': require('./assets/fonts/WorkSans-Regular.ttf'),
});

const onLayoutRootView = useCallback(async () => {
  if (fontsLoaded) {
    await SplashScreen.hideAsync();
}
}, [fontsLoaded]);

if (!fontsLoaded) {
     return <Text style={{ fontFamily: 'Inter-Black', fontSize: 30, color: '#000' }}>A 
carregar...</Text>;
}

const Stack = createNativeStackNavigator();

return (
<View onLayout={onLayoutRootView}>
  <NavigationContainer>
    <Stack.Navigator>
    <Stack.Screen name="Menu" component={Menu}/>
      <Stack.Screen 
        name="FEM Intro" 
        component={FEMIntro}
      />
    </Stack.Navigator>  
  </NavigationContainer>  
</View>
);}
```

My package.json:

```
{
  "name": "millervillagetycoon",
  "version": "1.0.0",
  "main": "node_modules/expo/AppEntry.js",
  "scripts": {
    "start": "expo start --tunnel",
    "android": "expo start --android",
    "ios": "expo start --ios",
    "web": "expo start --web"
  },
  "dependencies": {
    "@react-navigation/native": "^6.1.4",
    "@react-navigation/native-stack": "^6.9.10",
    "expo": "~47.0.12",
    "expo-app-loading": "^2.1.1",
    "expo-font": "~11.0.1",
    "expo-splash-screen": "~0.17.5",
    "expo-status-bar": "~1.4.2",
    "react": "18.1.0",
    "react-native": "0.70.5",
    "react-native-safe-area-context": "4.4.1",
    "react-native-screens": "~3.18.0",
    "react-native-svg-transformer": "^1.0.0",
    "react-native-web": "~0.18.9",
    "react-dom": "18.1.0",
    "@expo/webpack-config": "^0.17.2"
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "@babel/core": "^7.12.9"
  },
  "private": true
}
```

Thank you.

Comment: You might have better luck with a ttf if you can get it or convert the otf

Comment: Same error with ttf, unfortunelly. @Abe